# JavaScript .call() function "this" value returning 3

Tags: javascript

I was reading about the JavaScript .call() method on MSDN and saw the following code:

```
function callMe(arg1, arg2){
    var s = "";

    s += "this value: " + this;
    s += "<br />";
    for (i in callMe.arguments) {
        s += "arguments: " + callMe.arguments[i];
        s += "<br />";
    }
    return s;
}

document.write("Original function: <br/>");
document.write(callMe(1, 2));
document.write("<br/>");

document.write("Function called with call: <br/>");
document.write(callMe.call(3, 4, 5));

// Output: 
// Original function: 
// this value: [object Window]
// arguments: 1
// arguments: 2

// Function called with call: 
// this value: 3
// arguments: 4
// arguments: 5
```

From this document I understand that the purpose of `.call()` is:

> The call method is used to call a method on behalf of another object.
>   It allows you to change the this object of a function from the
>   original context to the new object specified by thisObj.

The main code in question is:

```
document.write(callMe.call(3, 4, 5));
```

Why does this return `3` as the `this` value? How is that the global object?

Comment: When using call or apply the first parameter is what is going to be the value of "this" in the function being äpply'd or call'd

Comment: How can you pass it 3 arguments, it only accepts 2.

Comment: that's some seriously funky code - I've _never_ seen `arguments` qualified with the enclosing function's name.  Try using Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) instead of MSDN.

Comment: Oh, and it also manages to abuse `for ... in` to read a pseudo-array ?!

Comment: @Mathemats Not true, JS won't restrict you on the number of arguments you supply, no matter what you put between the function parentheses. You can call it with more or less arguments than it is defined to accept. Besides, this `.call()` call only passes in 2 params: `4` and `5` (the `3` is used as the `this` value).

Comment: I just looked at MDN and it's a little more complex in its explanation

Comment: You should read the [Javascript Zen Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/) page, especially the part of [how `this` works](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#function.this). It might help you understand that `this` does not always refer to the global object (arguably when it does, it is a mistake).

Comment: @Alnitak discovering that `fn.arguments` is accessible has made me so happy! All my debugging needs shall now be satisfied in massive output logs `function trace() {
    var fn = trace;
    while (fn = fn.caller) console.log(fn), console.log(fn.arguments);
}`

Comment: @PaulS. although that won't work in ES5 `strict mode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the first parameter to `.call()` is the value for `this` inside the function you are calling. In your case, that is `3`.

Comment: Thanks. Even though that is correct It makes no since why an object with the name "3" is passed in

Comment: It is not an object with the name `3` (you cannot have variables starting with a number in JS anyway), it is literally the number 3.